# How to split input by ASCII control codes with Progress 4GL?

Tags: barcode, progress-4gl

how can I split this barcode by group separator with Progress? I've tried chr(29) without any luck.

Barcode scanned into Notepad++: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YIbw.png

Barcode scanned into input field: 2409271405202120330017100282

Thanks.

```
def var c as char no-undo.
def var i as int no-undo.

update c format "x(50)".

do i = 1 to length(c):
    message substr(c, i, 1) = chr(29).
end.
```

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that GS is an undefined control code.  So you need to make it be recognized.

Add the following to your terminal's entry in protermcap to define GS as F13:

:(F13)=\035:\

(The octal code for GS is \035 and F13 is an undefined function key -- so the combination should work.  I don't have a scanner to test with but this works for the control codes that I can type into my keyboard...)

Then use code like this:

```
define variable bc as character no-undo format "X(50)".

update bc editing:
  if lastkey = 313 then
    apply ".".  /* 313 is the code for F13 */
   else
    apply lastkey.
end.
```

This should cause "." to be inserted instead of GS.  Which will allow you to parse the string using "." rather than GS.

Answer (score 0):

It's a wild guess, but I'm thinking ENTRY(entry-num, barcode-string, "group-separator-string")?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
/* create a test file (otherwise not needed...)
 */

output to "barcode.dat".
put control "240927140520" chr(29) "2120330017" chr(29) "100282".
output close.

/* if you already have barcode.dat start here
 */

define variable m  as memptr    no-undo.
define variable bc as character no-undo.

set-size( m ) = 100.
input from "barcode.dat" binary no-convert.
import unformatted m.
input close.

bc = get-string( m, 1 ).

display
  entry( 1, bc, chr(29)) format "x(12)" skip
  entry( 2, bc, chr(29)) format "x(12)" skip
  entry( 3, bc, chr(29)) format "x(12)" skip
.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately this doesn't cover my needs. It works if I read the barcode from file, but I need to read it from frame input field ( im working with character based app ). Is Progress ignoring the ascii control codes?

Comment: I've added code sample to my question which doesn't work when reading barcode.

Comment: I will leave this answer here since it works for file input.  Now that we know your real problem is keyboard input see my other answer.